# How to set timezone in jvm using docker

Tags: docker, jenkins, timezone

cmd in centos7

```
docker run -e TZ=Asia/Shanghai -e JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=Asia/Shanghai" jenkins/jenkins:2.176
```

Log timezone is correct

Then change image from `jenkins/jenkins:2.176 to jenkins/jenkins:2.177`

Log timezone is wrong

how to set correct timezone from `jenkins/jenkins:2.177` ?

[image: output]